# Given When then scenario for automatic email notification

Tags: bdd, gherkin, user-stories

How would you write a Given when then construct for a email notification scenario where a notification has to be sent 1 business day after a particular state change?

Does this look right?

```
Given that I'm the system 
  and the user of a particular type T
  and the state is S
When it is 1 business day after the date state was changed to x
then send an email notification with xxx content.
```

The reason I  have  a doubt is that my understanding is that Given section us for preconditions which in this cases is A. particular type of user, B. state is S and C. it is 1 day past a the date the state changed.

If all these preconditions are in Given section, what will be in the when section? My understanding was that 'when' section is for the event trigger. There's no action other than running the notification job. So would this be correct?

```
Given the user of a particular type T
  and the state is S
  and it is 1 business day after the date state was changed to x
When the email notification process triggered
  then send an email notification to all users of type T with xxx content.
```

I'd appreciate your thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track!

So as you said before `When` is a trigger, so lets look into this deeper.

Gherkin is used for Behavior Driven Development (BDD) in that you are trying to simulate behavior.

**Given - Input - Prerequisites**

These are things that need are expected before the action or trigger occurs. They set up your tests for the action that will occur.

**When - Trigger - Action**

These are the users behavior that triggers the result. This is the B in BDD

**Then - Output - Result**

This is the end result, what should the user expect when the behavior completes.

**Where You Stand**

So you are in an interesting situation because as you pointed out, there is no behavior. So heres the tricky part, while having a Given-When-Then format is nice, its totally valid to have a Given-Then or a When-Then format as well in cases where there is no solid user behavior. So in that case:

```
Given it is 1 business day after the date state was changed to x
```

and

```
When it is 1 business day after the date state was changed to x
```

Are both equally as valid.

In regards to your second code block, the question you need to ask yourself is `the email notification process triggered` a trigger or a result? Personally I would say it is a result of the Inputs. If you do think you need it then I think you should write your test like this:

```
Given there is a user of type T
And the state is S
And it is 1 business day after the date state was changed to x
Then the email notification process should have triggered
And send an email notification to all users of type T with xxx content.
```

**Bonus -- How to word your test and avoid implementation language**

Not that you asked, but there is actually a way to improve your tests wording. You want to decouple your test from the actual implementation. What this means is avoid words like Send, Click, or Type and focus on behavior and result. Taking your test I would reword it like this:

```
Given there is a user of type T
And the state is S
And it is 1 business day after the date state was changed to x
Then all users of type T should be notified of xxx
```

I removed the email notification step because that can be inferred from the last step. I also decoupled the last step from implementation language. Whats important here isn't that the user gets sent an email, its that they are notified of the content. Your `Given` steps should also be changed in my opinion depending on your business logic as they are currently very coupled to your implementation.

Comment: What an amazing and enlightening answer.
.
I think the Given-Then approach makes complete sense. That was my first thought but I wanted to make sure that I staed true to the construct.

Comment: The bonus section is a big help. 

Is it fair to say that the objective to decouple behavior from implementation ? In your code snippet, the user will be "notified of the xxx" (behavior) but the how part is missing ( by email).  

As somebody who is writing the acceptance criterion, it seems to me that Prerequisite, Action and Result  is required but the how part (by email) is also required.

Given there is a user of type T
  and the state is S
  and it is 1 business day after the date state was changed to x
  Then all users of type T should be notified of xxx  _by email_

Comment: At the end of the day you have to do what fits your ACs, on my teams I usually try and decouple as much as possible because if the Implementation changes the ACs don't change. For example if The implementation changes from email to text, the AC has not changed, the user is still notified. What changed was how they were notified.

Comment: hmm. I have incorporated your suggestions on both the construct and the grammar and worded it in a way that the implementation is separate from the grammar.
Thanks for taking the time! This was super useful.